# playframework 2.2.0 scala mockito test

Tags: scala, mockito, playframework-2.2

I am currently trying to use Mockclasses in play framework for testing.
I have implemented everything like written in the Documentation. Unfortunately the compiler says:

```
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in MockitoStubs.class refers to term stubbing
[error] in package org.mockito which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling MockitoStubs.class.
```

I found some other people which are running play on a mac and have the same error but i could not find any solution.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Is it a problem with the mac jdk maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed the new OS X 10.9 Version which included a xCode Update and SDK Updates(I guess Java got updated too). Anyways the error does not occur anymore so it probably was a problem with the jdk...

Answer (score 0):

Mockito is an optional dependency (like most Play2 dependencies). Excerpt from my `Build.scala`:

```
"org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5"
```

Comment: "I have implemented everything like written in the Documentation." Therefore I already added mockito to my dependencies... As I stated in my Answer switching to the new Mac OS solved the problem without any codechange so I guess that it was a jdk problem...